# Windows 8.1: can't edit registry with a VBS called from an HTA while calling the VBS alone works fine

Tags: vbscript, registry, windows-8.1, hta

I'm developping a Windows 8.1 HTA realizing various operations. At some point, I need to insert values into the registry (for autologon and runonce purposes).

Here is the VBS code:

```
Sub RunOnce()

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strNewKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
strNewValue = "AppsInstaller"
strCurDir    = objShell.CurrentDirectory
strScriptPath = strCurdir & "\2_Install_Apps.hta"
objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strNewKeyPath, strNewValue, strScriptPath

End Sub

Function AutoLogon(strLogin, strPassword)

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strAutoLogon = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon"
objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\AutoAdminLogon", "1", "REG_DWORD"
objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\DefaultUserName", strLogin, "REG_SZ"
objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\DefaultPassword", strPassword, "REG_SZ"

End Function
```

I'm developping on a computer under Windows 7. When I call RunOnce and AutoLogon from an HTA launched with administrator rights, everything works fine. 
My target is a Surface Pro 3 under Windows 8.1. When I call RunOnce and AutoLogon from the HTA launched with administrive rights on this computer, the registry is not edited. But if I launch the following VBS file with admin rights, it's working fine.

```
Sub RunOnce()

    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    strComputer = "."
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    strNewKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
    strNewValue = "AppsInstaller"
    strCurDir    = objShell.CurrentDirectory
    strScriptPath = strCurdir & "\2_Install_Apps.hta"
    objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strNewKeyPath, strNewValue, strScriptPath

End Sub


Function AutoLogon(strLogin, strPassword)

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strAutoLogon = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon"
    objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\AutoAdminLogon", "1", "REG_DWORD"
    objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\DefaultUserName", strLogin, "REG_SZ"
    objShell.RegWrite strAutoLogon & "\DefaultPassword", strPassword, "REG_SZ"

End Function

RunOnce()
Test = AutoLogon("login", "password")
```

I really don't get what's going on here. It certainly has something to do with admin rights but I'm clueless and I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run your HTA with the 64 bit version of mshta.exe. (orcheck with the right bitness).

From Help.

> Registry Redirector
>
> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of key portions of the registry on WOW64.
>
> The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit registry calls to each logical registry view and maps them to the corresponding physical registry location.
>
> The redirection process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit Windows.
>
> Redirection is enabled for the following registry keys:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software
>
> HKEY_USERS*\Software\Classes
>
> HKEY_USERS*_Classes
>
> Note  * indicates a match for all user security IDs (SID).
>
> The following scenario illustrates the use of these logical views:
>
> A 32-bit application checks for the existance of the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Hello. If the key does not exist, it creates it with a default value of "Hello 32-bit world"; otherwise, it reads and displays the value.
>
> The same application is modified to write "Hello 64-bit world" instead of "Hello 32-bit world" and recompiled as a 64-bit application. 
>   When the 32-bit application is run on 64-bit Windows, it displays "Hello 32-bit world". When the 64-bit application is run, it displays "Hello 64-bit world". Both applications call the same registry functions with the same predefined handle and the same key name; the difference is that each application operates on its logical view of registry, and each view is mapped to a separate physical location of the registry, which keeps both versions of the string intact.
>
> To help applications that write REG_EXPAND_SZ keys containing %ProgramFiles% to the registry, WOW64 intercepts these writes and replaces them with "%ProgramFiles(x86)%". This environment variable is defined for all processes. For example, if the Program Files directory is on the C drive, then "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" expands to "C:\Program Files (x86)".
>
> To enable application interoperability through COM and other mechanisms, WOW64 uses registry reflection, which copies specific registry keys and values between the two registry views to keep them in synch. The reflector is intelligent and copies COM activation data for Local servers between the views, but not in-process data, because 32/64 in-process data mixing is not permitted on 64-bit Windows.
>
> For more information, see the following topics:
>
> Registry Reflection
>
> Shared Registry Keys
>
> Accessing an Alternate Registry View
>
> Example of Registry Reflection and Redirection on WOW64
>
> Remote Registry Access in 64-bit Windows
>
> Send comments about this topic to Microsoft
>
> Build date: 10/2/2006

Comment: Oh boy, you're a life savior. If I launch the hta with mshta 32 bits it's working!

Comment: Er, I mean if I use the mshta 64 bits it's working. I was modfying the 32 bits hive.